# Android Rect.intersects always returns false

Tags: java, android

I have 2 `ImageView` elements. The first `ImageView` is moving towards the second `ImageView`. I am trying to detect when they collide using Android's `Rect` but for some reason when the images collide, `Rect.intersects` still returns `false`.

```
ImageView tile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tt);
ImageView indicator = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ti);
final int[] loc = new int[2];
tile.getLocationInWindow(loc);
final Rect tileRect = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1],
    loc[0] + tile.getWidth(), loc[1] + tile.getHeight());
indicator.getLocationInWindow(loc);
    final Rect indicatorRect = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1],
loc[0] + indicator.getWidth(), loc[1] + indicator.getHeight());
```

I later check for collision like this:

```
if(Rect.intersects(tileRect, indicatorRect)){
    System.out.println("Intersects");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Doesn't intersect");
}
```

I can't seem to figure the problem out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of `tile.getWidth()`, `tile.getHeight()`, `indicator.getWidth()`, `indicator.getHeight()`?

Comment: tile: 135.0, 450 indicator: 152, 152

Comment: I'd suggest:
A) change your println statements to use Android's logging facilities
B) add all 4 coordinates of both rectangles to the logging

Comment: I have logged the position of rectangles (width, height, centerX, centerY) and noticed that it doesn't change when I move the ImageView. I thought that the rectangle automatically moves with it. I move my ImageView like this: tile.setY(tile.getY() + 5.0f); What is the equivalent function for Rect?

Comment: I solved it by updating the position. Thanks.